# How to run concrete5 in a subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, concrete5

I've put my [concrete5](http://concrete5.org) installation in the subfolder `/www/concrete5`. I've tried different entries in my .htaccess file but all modes seem to have some errors.

There is mainly one forum post about it

- [Domain root - CMS link problem](http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/domain_root_-_cms_link_problem)

but it does not seem to work in edit mode. However, this forum post is quite old.

Is there a simple way of accessing a concrete5 installation in a subdirectory as if it were in the root?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a detailed description on how to do this:
http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/hide-the-subdirectory-url/

Answer (score 1):

What does your site.php file look like?

I run a lot of cms sites from subdirectories and my htaccess file is pretty standard:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I do the directory specific settings in the site.php file in the config directory.

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://domain.com');
define('DIR_REL', '/dirname');
```

Comment: The thing is, you'd access your installation via the URL `http://domain.com/dirname/` instead of only the domain.